# why is my server side script only taking one client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to make a TCP chat room.
The code runs but when I connect my client-sides, message from 1 side does not go to other side . I really can't understand why it is happening

This is the server-side.

```
import threading
import socket


s=socket.socket()
IP='192.168.1.205'
print("the IP is ",IP)
PORT=5050
print("the port is ",PORT)
s.bind((IP,PORT))
s.listen(5)
client_connected =[]
name_list=[]

def broadcast(message,c):
    for c in client_connected:
        try:
            c.send(bytes(message,'utf-8'))
        except:
            c.shutdown()
            client_connected.remove(c)
            print(c," is removed")

        
        

def handler(c):
    c.send(bytes('enter your name','utf-8'))
    name=c.recv(1024)
    name_list.append(name)
    print(name,"has connected to the server")
    while True:
        message=c.recv(1024)
        broadcast(message,c)
    


def recieve():
    while True:
        c,addr=s.accept() 
        
        client_connected.append(c)
        #print("client_connected",client_connected)
        #print(len(client_connected))
        
        thread=threading.Thread(target=handler,args=(c,))
        thread.start()
        
    
recieve()
```

This is the client-side

```
import socket
import threading

c=socket.socket()
c.connect(('192.168.1.205',5050))
print(c.recv(1024))
c.send(bytes(input(":<;"),'utf-8'))


def recieve():
    while True:
        print("recieve")
        print(c.recv(1024))



def write():
    while True:
        print("write")
        c.send(bytes(input(":"),'utf-8'))

write()
recieve()
thread_recieve=threading.Thread(target=recieve)
thread_recieve.start()
thread_write=threading.Thread(target=write)
thread_write.start()
```

I know I have done some stupid things but please help me figure them out.

Comment: You are calling `handler()` in the same thread with the server `accept()` loop, and doing so *before* starting a new thread. What you want is to remove `handler(c)` and change the line after to `thread=threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(c,))`. NOTE: I did not check the code for other bugs/problems.

Comment: it works thanks but the message from client1 is not going to client2. can you also please help me with this

Comment: can you also explain me why did we add  "args=(c,))" part and what goes  "(c,)" mean

Comment: That's just an ugly but standard way of creating a python tuple with one element. The `args=` keyword expects a *sequence* of arguments, even when you are supplying only one argument. But if you write `args=(c)` then the expression `(c)` is simply parsed as a parenthesized expression instead of a tuple. I should have written `args=[c]` just for clarity's sake.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. And also I made the code work.